# Color Polygons Using GeoListPlot works individually, but not together

Tags: graphics, geography

I have following problem:

[image]

and

[image]

So far so good. But `GeoListPlot[{test[[;; 2]]}, ImageSize -> 300]` does nothing (produces a blank map).

Similarly, the code [here](http://pastebin.com/NfPHn0Kf) when plotted using `GeoListPlot[test]` shows only three regions, when it should be five (and all 5 are individually plottable).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `GeoListPlot[test[[;; 2]], ImageSize -> 300]`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It works for the first one, but for the second on (code in the link) I still can't get all five, no matter if the `{}` are there or not. In that case, I get two pieces if I use the braces, and the other two if I don't.

Comment: If you use Graphics instead of GeoListPlot it works. Might be because of the coordinates. What are they supposed to be?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries that really solves the problem. Is there a way to different sublists passed into graphics different colors? (that is what I was originally trying to do). As an aside, it seems the problem was that some of the regions had multiple polygons, and the others only had one, and you can't plot both at the same with with GeoListPlot for some reason

Comment: Graphics[Riffle[test, RandomColor[] // Unevaluated], ImageSize -> 300]

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries and any ideas on the core issue?

Comment: GeoListPlot[test /. {a : Polygon[__] ..} -> a, ImageSize -> 300]

Comment: or skip directly to `GeoGraphics[test, ImageSize -> 300]` (`GeoGraphics` instead of `GeoListPlot`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lat/long data pairs look like `{523679., 632989.}` which appear to be in some form of DMS form (ddmmss., ddmmss.}. However, I believe that these are being interpreted as decimal degrees. Converting to decimal degrees (simplified conversion used assuming longitude is even number of digits consistent with your data):

```
data = test /. 
    x_?NumericQ :> 
     FromDMS[FromDigits /@
       (x // Round // IntegerDigits //
         Partition[#, 2] &)] // N;

Manipulate[
 If[s === "All",
  func[data, ImageSize -> 500],
  func[data[[s]], ImageSize -> 300]],
 {{func, GeoListPlot, "Function"},
  {GeoListPlot, GeoGraphics}},
 {{s, "All", "Section"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "All"}},
 ControlType -> SetterBar]
```

[image]

Comment: These polygons look like they are probably projected into a State-Plane Coordinate System. If we know which state they belong to they can be projected back with `GeoGridPosition`

Comment: If the coordinates were the common "web mercator", you can convert them to `GeoPosition` coordinates doing `GeoPosition[GeoGridPosition[merc/(6378137. Degree), "Mercator"]]`, where `merc` is any web mercator coordinate pair.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you have coordinates that have been projected onto a cartesian system, I'm guessing a US state-plane system. Mathematica can deal with these, you just have to tell it what it's looking at.

So suppose these are from NY, in the eastern section. Then

```
test2 = test /. coords : {__?NumberQ} :> GeoPosition @ GeoGridPosition[coords, "SPCS83NY01"];

GeoListPlot @ test2
```

[image]